# compiling openCV code on mac 64bit

Tags: opencv, makefile

i've been trying to compile my code with openCV on mac 64bit. The following is my makefile contents:

```
OSTYPE := $(shell uname -s)

SRC_FILES = \
    ../RGB_display/main.cpp 

INC_DIRS += ../RGB_display

EXE_NAME = RGB_display

DEFINES = USE_GLUT

#opencv libraries
###################
CC = g++ 
DEBUG_LEVEL = -m64 -g3 -O0 
CFLAGS = -O3 -I/opt/local/include/opencv -L/opt/local/lib/
LIBS = -lhighgui -lcvaux -lcv -lml -lcxcore
.SUFFIXES: .o .cc

LDFlags = `pkg-config --libs opencv` -opencv_imgproc
####################
#end add

ifeq ("$(OSTYPE)","Darwin")
        LDFLAGS += -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
else
        USED_LIBS += glut
endif

include ../NiteSampleMakefile
```

However I get the following error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? I know its with regards to my mac being on a 64 bit system, but I have tried adding DEBUG_LEVEL = -m64 and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you installed 64-bit OpenCV libraries? (Or Universal Binaries) That should be your problem.

Using the "file" command on your OpenCV libraries should tell you what architectures they provide.

Comment: It says 

"libcv.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64"

so I guess it is? I am puzzled because I had the same problem with another code and it was solved by adding the DEBUG_LEVEL line. However, it doesn't work now...

Comment: @Esther What about libhighgui, libcvaux, libml and libcxcore?

Comment: ok i think i got it. in opencv2, the libraries are named differently. They are opencv_highgui, opencv_cvaux etc. Also, in my common make file, there are these two lines:

CFLAGS += -arch i386 -arch x86_64
LDFLAGS += -arch i386 -arch x86_64

I removed -arch i386 for both and it worked. Thanks!